# How to save input in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

I am writing a script, I would like to be able to add a user and assign a command to it.

So basically i want to edit script while it's runnning.
Is it possible in bash?

I have already written the basics, this is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
#title:         menu.sh
#==============================================================================


#Menu options
#options[seq]="$varname"
options[0]="user1"
options[1]="user2"
options[2]="Guser3"
options[3]="user4"
options[4]="add user"


#Actions to take based on selection

function ACTIONS {
    if [[ ${choices[0]} ]]; then
        #Option 1 selected
        echo "user1 selected"
    fi
    if [[ ${choices[1]} ]]; then
        #Option 2 selected
        echo "user2 selected"
    fi
    if [[ ${choices[2]} ]]; then
        #Option 3 selected
        echo "user3 selected"
    fi
    if [[ ${choices[3]} ]]; then
        #Option 4 selected
        echo "user4 selected"
    fi
    if [[ ${choices[4]} ]]; then
        #Option 5 selected
        echo "new user added"

        read -p "Enter username name:  " sname
        read -p "Enter comand to save for this user:  " cname
        echo Adding  $sname to list with $cname comand
        
    fi
}

#Variables
ERROR=" "

#Clear screen for menu
clear

#Menu function
function MENU {
    echo "Menu Options"
    for NUM in ${!options[@]}; do
        echo "[""${choices[NUM]:- }""]" $(( NUM+1 ))") ${options[NUM]}"
    done
    echo "$ERROR"
}

#Menu loop
while MENU && read -e -p "Select the desired options using their number (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): " -n1 SELECTION && [[ -n "$SELECTION" ]]; do
    clear

    if [[ "$SELECTION" == *[[:digit:]]* && $SELECTION -ge 1 && $SELECTION -le ${#options[@]} ]]; then
        (( SELECTION-- ))
        if [[ "${choices[SELECTION]}" == "+" ]]; then
            choices[SELECTION]=""
        else
            choices[SELECTION]="+"
        fi
            ERROR=" "
    else
        ERROR="Invalid option: $SELECTION"
    fi
    set -e

done

ACTIONS
```

Thats the code,

## Actions to take based on selection

## Actions to take based on selection

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have an array `options`, and you want to add users to this array on the fly? So that the next time your `ACTION` function executes, you get an additional entry listed as an option?

Comment: Yes, thats  right. I want to add user on the fly.

Comment: Yes, this would be possible, but not by editing your scripts. Instead add an input file, and read users from there. e.g. `i=0; while read -r user; do options[$i]="$user"; ((i++)) done < inputfile; options[$i]="add user"` If this approach suits you I can add a fuller answer

Comment: Yes, please add fuller answer if you can.

Comment: Sorry for long replay but i was on holidays, I will be grateful add fuller answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned, two files. One contains a `userlist`, and one your script, `menu.sh`

```
userlist:

user1
user2
Guser3
user4
```

Take input from userlist, and initialise your count variable, `i`. I wrapped this in a function: `get_users`

```
get_users() {
i=0
while read -r user
do
 options[$i]="$user"
 ((i++))
done < userlist

options[$i]="add user"
}
```

Add `get_users` to your MENU Function. This will read the userlist everytime menu is called.

```
function MENU {
    get_users
    echo "Menu Options"
    for NUM in ${!options[@]}; do
        echo "[""${choices[NUM]:- }""]" $(( NUM+1 ))") ${options[NUM]}"
    done
    echo "$ERROR"
}
```

Finally, ensure that you append any new users to your `userlist` file:

```
echo "$sname" >> userlist
```

Please note:

You will need to add a more systematic way to echo your choices in your `ACTIONS` function. As you've explicitly specified what a choice should be, option 4 will always return new user for example.

You can do so with something like:

```
function ACTIONS {
    for (( c=0; c<=$(expr ${#options[@]} - 1); c++ ))
    do
    if [[ ${choices[$c]} ]]; then
        #Option 1 selected
        echo "user$(expr $c + 1) selected"
    fi
    done
    if [[ ${choices[$i]} ]]; then # $i is from the new get_users function - convenient way to get the last number from the array
        #Option 5 selected
        echo "new user added"

        read -p "Enter username name:  " sname
        read -p "Enter comand to save for this user:  " cname
        echo Adding  $sname to list with $cname comand
        echo "$sname" >> userlist
    fi
}
```